# Geting a maximum value in code iginiter function

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

I'm using this function to recover a maximum value in a table in code igniter. But it's returning no value. Actually it's recovering a null value from the table, and I think it is not dealing with a variable as integer. Here is my code:

```
public function MaxWork($n)
{
    $this->db->select_max('w_no');
    $this->db->where('n_no', $n);
    $query = $this->db->get('t_detail');
    foreach ($query->result() as $row)
    {
        $no = $row->w_no;
    }
    if($no == '')
    $no = 1;
    return($no);
    }   
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to remove this line **$this->db->where('n_no', $n);** and check the results ?

Comment: Try `echo $this->db->last_query();exit;` after `$query = $this->db->get('t_detail');` and place this query within sql and check are you getting values within it

Comment: No still the same issue. Ys i removed $this->db->where('n_no', $n) but no Result :-(

Answer (score 0):

```
    public function MaxWork($n)
    {
        $this->db->select_max('w_no');
        $this->db->where('n_no', $n);
        $this->db->group_by('n_no');
        $query = $this->db->get('t_detail');

        if($query->num_rows() > 0)
            return $query->row()->w_no;
        else
            return 1; // default 1 as per your requirement for null records         
    }
```

no need for foreach

Comment: I was thinking that it will definitely work but surprisingly its not working. I have checked the function only returns string Not any integer. I have removed the query and initialize a variable with a number and then used exit statement. Again the screen is blank. How ever if i store a string in that variable it works fine. I DON'T KNOW WHY????